# CMake MacOS frameworks not being linked properly?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, core-foundation

Using CLion IDE and CMake to compile my project with c++ and a couple objective-c++ classes.

**My problem arose because I need to include CoreFoundation in my project for my class in a .mm file to inherit from NSObject**

After much digging, I think I found the modern CMake way of linking MacOS frameworks (CoreBluetooth, CoreFoundation, etc) with cmake.

Code below is the modern way of finding and linking MacOS frameworks in my Cmakelists.txt file:

```
target_link_libraries(project_name PUBLIC stdc++ "-framework CoreBluetooth"
                                            "-framework Foundation"
                                            "-framework CoreFoundation"
    objc)
```

Loading cmake does not throw any errors, but when I try to `import` the files (in either my .cpp or .mm files) the IDE is saying that it cannot find the CoreBluetooth and Foundation libraries.

Not sure if I am missing anything really obvious. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after going on several wild goose hunts and layers and layers of digging, I finally found a solution. I printed out the location of CoreFoundation to make sure it was being found correctly and the directory is good:

```
find_library(FoundationLib CoreFoundation)
message("LIB: ${FoundationLib}")
```

-> `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework`
Okay so I am almost certain is being loaded correctly. Now I dug deeper and broke my code and discovered that CLion accepts other extensions such as .h++ and **.hm**

.hm looks really similar to .h, and I know that the .m extension denotes an objective c file so that must mean I should probably use .hm to represent an objective-c header. So I renamed my header with the .hm extension and it works now. I think this is CLion specific and has not been documented anywhere.

recap: on CLion rename your objective c header from .h -> .hm

and if your header is an objective c++ header, change from .h -> .hmm

FINAL RECAP: I changed the header files back from .hm and .hmm -> .h, and they still work. So final answer for my issue is on CLion you have to set objective c++ headers to .hmm and .hm temporarily then you set them back to .h

Comment: I think the files that you include the headers into matter, not the headers themselves. C++ files can use C++ syntax, Objective C can use Objective C syntax.